# Imports in __init__.py

Tags: python

This is my project structure (Python 3.5.1.):

```
a
├── b.py
└── __init__.py
```

### Case 1

- File `b.py` is empty.
- File `__init__.py` is:

  ```
  print(b)
  ```

If we run `import a`, the output is:

```
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

### Case 2

- File `b.py` is empty.
- File `__init__.py` is:

  ```
  import a.b
  print(b)
  ```

If we run `import a`, the output is:

```
<module 'a.b' from '/tmp/a/b.py'>
```

### Question

Why doesn't the program fail in Case 2?

Usually if we run `import a.b` then we can only reference it by `a.b`, not `b`. Hopefully somebody can help explain what's happening to the namespace in Case 2.

Comment: I think it's probably because `b` is introduced to the namespace of `a` by the `import a.b` statement. But I'm not sure about the details. Nor do I know whether it's an explicitly supported feature.

Comment: @shx2 Both `a` and `b`. `a` should be there. But why is `b` also there? The most logical thing I can guess is: `a` is introduced into the current scope, then `b` is introduced into the scope of `a`. But the current scope is the same as the scope of `a` when executing `a/__init__.py`. Need confirmation.

Comment: @shx2: yes, that's the *point* of the question. Why is `b` there *too*? It was never explicitly imported. `import a.b` only adds `a`, normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python adds modules as globals to the parent package after import.

So when you imported `a.b`, the name `b` was added as a global to the `a` module, created by `a/__init__.py`.

From the [Python 3 *import system* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules):

> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism (e.g. importlib APIs, the import or import-from statements, or built-in `__import__()`) a **binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object**. For example, if package `spam` has a submodule `foo`, after importing `spam.foo`, `spam` will have an attribute `foo` which is bound to the submodule.

Bold emphasis mine. Note that the same applies to Python 2, but Python 3 made the process more explicit.

Answer (score -1):

An `import` statement brings a module into scope. You imported `b`, so there it is, a module object.

Read the documentation for [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import):

> The basic import statement (no from clause) is executed in two steps:
>
> - find a module, loading and initializing it if necessary
> - define a name or names in the local namespace for the scope where the import statement occurs.

You didn't import `b` in the first case.

Comment: I wouldn't be very suprised if Case 1 fails. If you run `import a.b; print(b)` in a `__main__` script then it will fail. But it doesn't fail in Case 2 here.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: `import a.b` binds the name `a` in a namespace. What is special here is that `b` is a submodule of `a` and thus the import internals set the name `b` in the namespace of `a`. That results in a global `b` in that the namespace of `a`, i.e. `__init__.py`. If this was *any other module* the name `b` would not have appeared like this.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: In other words, *they didn't import `b` in the second case either*, but it was added *anyway*.